# Flutter: Update TextFormField text with ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, changenotifier

In a complex scenario I need to update the text of some `TextFormField`s when a `notifyListeners()` is sent by a Model extending `ChangeNotifier`.
The problem is that to change the text of a `TextFormField` you have to use the setter `TextFormField.text` which implies a rebuild, and so you can't use it into the `build` method. But to access the `Provider` of the model you need the `context` which is inside the `build` method.

MWE (obviously the button is in another Widget in the real project, and there are more `TextFormField`s)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  void updateCounter() {
    ++_counter;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  MyModel() {
    _counter = 1;
  }

  int _counter;
  String get counter => _counter.toString();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _text1Ctl = TextEditingController();
  var _text2Ctl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final model = MyModel();
    model.addListener(() {
      _text1Ctl.text = model.counter;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).updateCounter();
        },
        child: Text('Press me'),
      ),
      // 1st attempt
      // Doesn't work because the listener isn't applied to the instance of the model provided by the provider.
      TextFormField(controller: _text1Ctl),
      // 2nd attempt
      // Works but with `Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` because it changes text via controller (which implies a rebuild) during building.
      Consumer<MyModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
        _text2Ctl.text = model.counter;
        return TextFormField(controller: _text2Ctl);
      })
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example works without any errors when I run it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  void updateCounter() {
    ++_counter;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  MyModel() {
    _counter = 1;
  }

  int _counter;
  String get counter => _counter.toString();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _text2Ctl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false).updateCounter();
        },
        child: Text('Press me'),
      ),

      // 2nd attempt
      // Works but with `Another exception was thrown: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` because it changes text via controller (which implies a rebuild) during building.
      Consumer<MyModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
        _text2Ctl.text = model.counter;
        return TextFormField(controller: _text2Ctl);
      })
    ]));
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Very strange... maybe it's a problem with Chrome device (I'm not using Android/iOs emulator but Chrome to test)